# How to restart AsteriskWin32 via CLI Command?

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, asterisk

When I used "reload" command, it didn't truly reloading all module like Asterisk start from beginning. So, when I just used "reload" command, I couldn't register SIP with my client application.
Is there any command that more truly restart the Asterisk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`restart now` should work for you. If you have any concerns with a specific module, you can always try to do the following:

```
module load name_of_module.so

module unload name_of_module.so
```

Comment: I have moved my system to linux. it's running now, with /etc/init.d/asterisk restart